# Javascript replace strings with substrings that comes from Array

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how to replace in string substring that is stored in array of substrings and do it the best way. I was reading about `RegEx` and `String.replace()` method but can't find working example. The goal is to remove from company name the substring such as ".ltd" or "ltd"

**My code:**

```js
function removeCompanySubstring(string) {
  var regex = companySubstrings
  console.log(regex)
  return string.replace(regex, "");
}
console.log(removeCompanySubstring("Company .ltd"))
```

**companySubstrings.json**

```
"companySubstrings": [
        "ltd.",
        ".ltd",
        "GmbH",
        ...
    ],
```

When I call the function `removeCompanySubstring("Company GmbH")` the output is wrong and it returns

`> Company GmbH`

But the outpt should be

`> Company`

and it should remove the "Gmbh" from Company

Comment: Do you want to replace each item in the `companySubstrings` array with empty space?

Comment: I want to check if string contain any substring from companySubstrings and if it does, then replace it with blank ""

Comment: what other substrings are in `companySubstrings` ?

Comment: @Nick the other substrings are: "s.a", "a.s", "gmbh", "limited", etc

Comment: An array is not a regexp, use RegExp constructor: `regex = new RegExp(companySubstrings.join('|'), 'i');`.

Comment: @Teemu does not work with `"Company GmbH .ltd".replace(regex, '')`. Removes just first hit.

Comment: Ooops, I forgot the `g` flag, should've been `regex = new RegExp(companySubstrings.join('|'), 'gi');`.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the `.` before creating the regex (otherwise `altd` would match like `.ltd`), and make sure you understand about the limitations of these methods, see my answer for some edge-cases

Answer (score 1):

#### Watch out for edge-cases!

In terms of implementation, you can:

- build your regex as @Teemu said (without forgetting to **escape the `.` character which is a substitute for any character** in the regex world)
- or loop over the array and replace any occurrence of the substrings

No matter what method you choose, you should finally trim the string to remove any trailing/leading whitespace left.

**Although it's far from being bulletproof methods:** consider what happens if you change lowercase to uppercase? Sure you can make it case insensitive using a regex, but then what if the pattern is also found within the actual name of the company?

For instance "limited" which you listed as a possible substring can be found in a company name like "Unlimited clothing limited". The french "SAS" could be found in "SASUN GmbH"...

**And this gets worse the longer `companySubstrings` gets** because you'll be more and more likely to find one of the patterns within a legit company name as you keep adding new patterns.

Also, should the substring be found multiple time in a company name, should we replace just a single occurrence? Then which one: first, last? Another one? Same question for when we find different substrings in the same company name.

Turns out it's not such a trivial problem at all.

#### Two different implementations, with their own shortcomings

```js
var companySubstrings = [
  "SAS",
  "limited",
  "ltd.",
  ".ltd",
  "GmbH"
];

// Using a regex to replace all occurrences (case insensitive)
function removeCompanySubstringRegex(string) {
  // If the companySubstrings are never changing, you should declare
  // the regex as a const outside of this function so you don't
  // build a new regex each time you call it
  return string.replace(
    new RegExp(
      companySubstrings
        .join('|')
        .replaceAll('.', '\\.'),
      'gi' // g: replace all - i: case insensitive
    ),
    ''
  ).trim();
}

// Looping over the substrings array to replace matches (case sensitive)
function removeCompanySubstringLoop(string) {
  let result = string;
  companySubstrings.forEach(
    // use `result.replaceAll(str, '')` to replace **all** occurrences
    // and get the same behavior as the `g` flag in a regex
    str => result = result.replace(str, '')
  );
  return result.trim();
}

// Loop:  `SAS Company .ltd` -> `Company` ✅
console.log(
  'Loop: ',
  removeCompanySubstringLoop("SAS Company .ltd")
);

// Regex:  `SAS Company .ltd` -> `Company` ✅
console.log(
  'Regex: ',
  removeCompanySubstringRegex("SAS Company .ltd")
)

// Loop:  `Unlimited  limited` -> `Un  limited` 
console.log(
  'Tricky name (loop): ',
  removeCompanySubstringLoop("Unlimited  limited")
)

// Regex:  `Unlimited  limited` -> `Un` 
console.log(
  'Tricky name (regex): ',
  removeCompanySubstringRegex("Unlimited  limited")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an array as regex. You have to loop over. See the snippet.

```js
var companySubstrings = [
  "ltd.",
  ".ltd",
  "GmbH",
];

function removeCompanySubstring(string) {
  for (var needle of companySubstrings) {
    string = string.replace(needle, "");
  }
  return string.trim();
}

console.log(removeCompanySubstring("Company GmbH .ltd"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a case insensitive version :)

```js
let companySubstrings = [
  "SAS",
  "ltd.",
  ".ltd",
  "GmbH",
];

function removeCompanySubstring(compName) {
  let result = compName;
  companySubstrings.forEach(str => {
    let regex = RegExp(str, 'gi');
    result = result.replace(regex, '')
  });
  return result.trim();
}

console.log(removeCompanySubstring("SAS Company .ltd"))
console.log(removeCompanySubstring("Company .ltd"));
console.log(removeCompanySubstring("Company GmbH"));
console.log(removeCompanySubstring("LTD. Company GmbH"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the approach you want to solve, I would suggest you to just create a Regex for the Array of strings you are getting in response.

```
function removeCompanySubstring(string) {
  regexArr = new RegExp(companySubstrings.join("|"), 'gi'); 
  return string.replace(regexArr, "");
}
 console.log(removeCompanySubstring("Company .ltd"))
```

ex-

```
 var arr = ["ltd.", ".ltd","GmbH"]; //the array you have
 var regexArr = new RegExp(arr.join("|"), 'gi'); //the regex you need
```

then follow the similar approach you are now using just update **regex** with **regexArr** you have created.